# How should I use the request.ip accessor from Geocoder to get user current ip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am having a difficult time finding how to use Geocoder gem on my Rails app to get and save the IP address when creating a new instance of User.

Geocoder has some useful functionalities such as accessors to get current ip location and some other locations information but I'm very new with Rails and it would have been perfect if the documentation had a bit more guidance :-)

As long as I'm using ActiveRecord I started by creating the following migration:

```
rails generate migration AddIpAddressToUser ip_address:float
```

Then I've added this into app/models/user.rb

```
geocoded_by :ip_address,
  :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
after_validation :geocode
```

I ran the migration to add these modification on schema.rb:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Now there is the current schema of User model: User.rb has a latitude, longitude and ip_address on its schema.

Being there how could I use the following methods ?

1. request.ip
2. request.location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails models are not request aware. So to assign the IP to the user you need to do it from the controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) do |u|
      u.ip_address = request.location
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

If you are using Devise you can just override the `build_resource` method:

```
# Adds request IP to the user to determine location.
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def build_resource(hash={})
    super(hash.merge(ip_address: request.location))
  end
end

# routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "my_registrations"}
```

Comment: Thanks @max. Worked well by overriding Devise default behavior 

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#class-ActionController::Base-label-Requests):

> For every request, the router determines the value of the controller
>   and action keys. These determine which controller and action are
>   called. The remaining request parameters, the session (if one is
>   available), and the full request with all the HTTP headers are made
>   available to the action through accessor methods. Then the action is
>   performed.
>
> The full request object is available via the request accessor

So, when a user visits your website or API call is send to your application, in the controller, you have an access to `request` object. It is up to you how you will use this data.

For instance, in the `index` method in your controller you can have something like:

```
def index
  geocoder_result = request.location
  #do something based on the geocoder_result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the country location based on geocoder using this

country = ISO3166::Country.new(Geocoder.search(ip).first.country_code)

we are using this to get the info on country and default currency of that IP location.